# Use sed and regex to replace sections of a configuration file

Tags: awk, sed

I have a configuration file structured as follows:

```
[section1]
path = <path1>
read only = yes
guest ok = yes

[section2]
path = <path2>
read only = no
guest ok = yes
```

I would need to be able to **replace a whole section** of the configuration file with a new section using the **sed** command.
Example of what I would like to achieve:

```
sudo sed -E -i ':a;N;$!ba;\[section1\]<regex_match_until_end_of_section1>/<new_section_1>/' <config_path>
```

Expected result:

```
<new_section_1>

[section2]
path = <path2>
read only = no
guest ok = yes
```

```
sudo sed -E -i ':a;N;$!ba;\[section2\]<regex_match_until_end_of_section2>/<new_section_2>/' <config_path>
```

Expected result:

```
[section1]
path = <path1>
read only = yes
guest ok = yes

<new_section_2>
```

Comment: if `awk` is okay, you can use empty `RS` to operate paragraph wise

Comment: it is not a problem to use `awk`, I had started to do some tests with the `sed` command because I had found some examples online

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `sed` may be able to do this but using `awk` is much more intuitive and clean:

```sh
awk -v s='[section1]' -v RS= '$1 == s {$0 = "<new_section_1>"}
{ORS=RT} 1' file

<new_section_1>

[section2]
path = <path2>
read only = no
guest ok = yes
```

Or:

```sh
awk -v s='[section2]' -v RS= '$1 == s {$0 = "<new_section_2>"} 
{ORS=RT} 1' file

[section1]
path = <path1>
read only = yes
guest ok = yes

<new_section_2>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but running the awk command gives me the original file output. `awk -v s='[section1]' -v RS= '$1 == s {$0 = "<new_section_1>"} {ORS=RT} 1' /home/my_user/test.conf`

Comment: If you're using `gnu-awk` then use: `awk -i inplace -v s='[section1]' -v RS= '$1 == s {$0 = "<new_section_1>"} {ORS=RT} 1' /home/my_user/test.conf`

Comment: Otherwise use: `awk -v s='[section1]' -v RS= '$1 == s {$0 = "<new_section_1>"} {ORS=RT} 1' /home/my_user/test.conf > _tmp && mv _tmp /home/my_user/test.conf`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works as expected. However, I noticed that if there are comments before the section I am interested in replacing, the command cannot replace the section, what is the cause?

Comment: `-v RS=` works by splitting input on empty lines. So if your sections have some empty lines within then it might be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples only(considering that in between a complete section you don't have new lines but your sections are separated by new lines) please try following `awk` code, written and tested with GNU `awk` should work in any `awk`. Where `s1` is `awk` variable which has value to be compared(for section) and `s2` is containing new value in it.

```
awk -v s1='[section1]' -v s2='<new_section_1>' '
$0~/^\[/{
  val=found=""
  if($0==s1){ found=1   }
}
!NF{
  if(!found){ print val }
  else      { print s2  }
}
{
  val=(val?val ORS:"")$0
}
!NF
END{
  if(!found){ print val }
}
'  Input_file
```